# Modify specific characters within String ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replace

So we have the following:

```
ArrayList<String> list = ( new ArrayList<String>( ) );

list.add( new String( "hello" ) ); // add first word at position [0]
list.add( new String( "world" ) ); // add second word at position [1]
```

I do not want to use the .replace method as that will replace ALL the occurrences. Suppose I only want to modify the first "l" in the hello word and change it to "x", how would I do that? I only want to target a specific element # within the string within the array.

```
System.out.println( list ); // display the full arraylist
```

Initial Output:

```
[hello, world]
```

Desired Output:

```
[hexlo, world]
```

Comment: May we see what code you've tried?

Comment: Don't use `new String()` for a string literal. You're creating an extra object for nothing.

Comment: You could use the `replaceFirst()` method or use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` and use the `setCharAt()` method.

Comment: Besides the obsolete `new String(…)` creation; you don't need to put `new ArrayList<String>()` in braces.

Comment: I think that the question was about working with lists and not only about replacing the characters in strings... it is definetely not an EXACT duplicate of those two answers... You have to consider that you can't change the string "in-place", so you have to manage the addition and removal of the list elements

Answer (score 0):

You for example can use the `list.set()` Method like so:

```
list.set(index, list.get(index).modifyingStringMethodhere());
```

Modifying the String, to your desires, is pretty simple, there are tons of tools that `java` natively supports.

Comment: modifyingStringMethodhere doesn't exist anywhere